# App doesn't load after migrating from Angular 7 to 8

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6, angular-upgrade

Migrated my app from Angular 7 to 8 and everything works fine. Unfortunately when deployed on AWS S3 when trying to open in it in a browser (Safari, Chrome) this error appears in the console:

TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this._android')

and nothing loads. Blank screen

I checked ci build and it uses correct node version 10.16.0 the same I use on my development machine.
Googling doesn't give me anytyhing :(

I expect page to load the same on local machine and S3

Comment: Did you find a fix?

Comment: And it works locally? Even built version?